# Pick 5 Latest DISTINCT rows

Tags: python, django

My model looks like this:

```
class UserRating(models.Model):

    RATING_CATEGORIES = (
        1: 'Bad',
        2: 'Boring',
        3: 'Average',
        4: 'Good',
        5: 'Great'
    )

    for_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='for_user')
    by_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='by_user')
    rating_category = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CATEGORIES)
    points = models.IntegerField(_('Points'), default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created'))
```

Now i want to select 5 latest rows according to `rating_category` in which `by_user` has rated `for_user`.

I have done something like this:

```
entries = UserRating.objects.values('rating_category').filter(
        for_user=for_user,
        by_user=by_user).order_by('-created')[:5]
```

But it return duplicate rows based on `rating_category`.

Lets assume i have following MySQL table entries:

```
id for_user by_user rating_category points         created
 1    1        1           1          100     2012-09-28 00:19:00
 2    1        1           2          100     2012-09-28 00:18:00
 3    1        1           4          100     2012-09-28 00:17:00
 4    1        1           4           0      2012-09-28 00:16:00
 5    1        1           3          100     2012-09-28 00:15:00
 6    1        1           5           0      2012-09-27 00:19:00
 7    1        1           2           0      2012-09-26 00:18:00
```

The desired output is:
`rowid-1, rowid-2, rowid-3, rowid-5, rowid-6`

Only Distinct rows based on `rating_category` but `latest` according to `created` date.

Comment: I read this 3 times and I'm still not exactly sure what you want to get back from the query. I could just be missing something, but if you don't get an answer soon, you might consider adding a bit more information.  For example, do you know the SQL that you are hoping to produce?  vs what you are actually getting?  That might help someone answer.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @DavidS i have added a sample data and desired output please check

Comment: Why is rowid-6 not included?  It's the only rating_category value of 5.  Is this a mistake?  Or am I missing something?  It seems like you want: rowid-1, rowid-2, rowid-3, rowid-5, rowid-6

Comment: yes i wrote that with mistake i have fixed that before your comment, you got exactly right

Comment: And do you just want the id value back?  or the whole record?

Comment: whole record, because i have to perform some operation later on

Comment: or may be a list of dictionaries with keys `rating_category` and `created`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is a red herring here. What you want to do is to group your records by `rating_category` and then for each group pick the one with the most recent creation date. So you want a query like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max
entries = (UserRating.objects.filter(for_user = for_user, by_user = by_user)
           .values('rating_category')
           .annotate(last_created = Max('created'))
           .order_by('-last_created'))[:5]
```

This returns dictionaries with keys `rating_category` and `last_created`.